# Python Append to Predefined List of Lists (What's going on under the hood here?)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to initialize an empty list as [[], []] and then append to it. However, I am getting unexpected results with the following method vs another. What is going on under the hood in this scenario?

```
y = [[]] * 2
print(y)
y[0].append(1)
y[1].append(2)
print(y)
```

output:

```
[[],[]]
[[1,2], [1,2]]
```

While this following code gives me the intended results that I want.

```
x = [[], []]
print(x)
x[0].append(1)
x[1].append(2)
print(x)
```

output:

```
[[],[]]
[[1], [2]]
```

Comment: I'd say most likely when you use `[value] * 2`, the value gets copied, whether it's a value or a reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @Moosefeather That does answer my question, thank you.